# Spark: Would a dataframe repartitioned to one node experience a shuffle when a groupBy is called on it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Suppose I have some data that is all on the same partition (I performed a `.coalesce(1)` on the dataframe previously). I would now like to group the data and perform aggregations on it. If I used `.groupBy` on the dataframe, would the groups be placed onto different nodes?

I would like to avoid this if it is true as I would like to perform these calculations on the groups without shuffling too much.

Answer (score 1):

First, `coalesce(1)` doesn't guarantee that all your data will be in a single node, to be soure you have to use `repartition(1)`, this will force to unite in a single node all your data. `coalesce` only groups partitions in the same node, so if your data is distributed in 5 nodes (multiple partitions in each), it will keep 5 partitions at the end. `repartition` force a shuffle, to move all your data to a single node.

But, if your concern is the number of partitions in aggregations, it depends, if the aggregation is only a `reduce` of all your data, spark sql will try to reduce first in each node, and then reduce the result of each node, an example will be a count. But for bucketized aggregations, like counting the number of elements with an id, what spark do is first reduces in each node, and then shuffle the data, into buckets, to be sure that all the reductions of each node, for the same id are in the same node, and reduce them again. The number of buckets is configured with the property `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, and each one will be executed as a task in your job. Be careful because setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to one could make other parts of your process slower like joins or big aggregations, or result in out of memory errors.

Comment: So `repartition(1)` is the equivalent of setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to `1`? So there would be no reshuffiling when a `groupBy` is performed after a `repartition(1)`?

Comment: Not exacly equivalent, a repartition force to unite all the data to the amount of partitions especified, but the next transformation applyied to the dataframe, in this case groupBy, will force to make a new repartition according to the 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' value

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It depends. By default, the number of partitions is defined by `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` . One way to avoid this is to use `repartition` with explicit partitioning expression instead of `coalesce`:

```
val df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(
  sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(1, "a"), Row(1, "b"), Row(2, "c"))),
  StructType(List(StructField("foo", IntegerType, true), StructField("bar", StringType, true))))
df.repartition(numPartitions = 1, $"foo").groupBy("foo").agg(count("*")).explain()
```

In general one can use the Spark web UI and monitor the shuffle read/write metrics on the "Stages" tab.

Comment: So if I repartition everything to one node, there shouldn't be any shuffling? Also, what is actually the difference between `repartition` and `coalesce` here?

Comment: @suleydaman Repartition already shuffles the data and allows explicitly specifying the partitioning. See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2868